# iframe GA not being tracked in mobile app webview

Tags: iframe, webview, google-analytics, mobile-application

Overview, I have an `<iframe>` embed on a content, inside has it's own GA library and track pageview and events defined. Currently the tracking is working in WEB and mobile web view but unfortunately when the embed is called in mobile app as a webview it is not tracking the pageview and events. Can anyone explain what may went wrong , why GA is not tracking?

In addition with this, currently the working environment and setting is in Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in mobile app, that the cookies are not automatically created even if it's in webview as these cookies are track by GA. The way to fix is to let the mobile app dev to enable those cookies so that GA will work